# using z transform pairs to solve the question.

Tags: z-transform

Following is a question about the z transform with:
$$ (-\frac{1}{3})^n \, u(-n-2). $$
Now, I know that a transform pair similar to this is:
$$ -\alpha^n \, u(-n-1) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha z^{-1}}. $$
Now using that property what I get is:
$$ \frac{1}{1-(1/3)z^{-1}}. $$
Since the shift is of $-1$ so using that property my final answer is:
$$ (z^{-1})(\frac{1}{1-(1/3)z^{-1}}). $$

Is it correct?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you help me on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written the result is incorrect. Using the definition of the unit step function then it is seen that
$$ u(-n -2) = \begin{cases} 1 && n\leq -2 \\ 0 && n > -2 \end{cases} $$
and yields
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n \, u(-n-2) \, z^{-n} = 0.$$

If the unit step function is $u(n-2)$,
$$ u(n -2) = \begin{cases} 1 && n \geq 2 \\ 0 && n < 2 \end{cases}, $$
then the transform is as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n \, u(n-2) \, z^{-n} &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a}{z} 
\right)^n = \frac{a^2}{z^2} \, \frac{1}{1 - \frac{a}{z}} = \frac{a^2}{z(z-a)}. 
\end{align}